# Scala newbie, understanding Akka actor pattern matching example

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, akka

I am a Scala newbie. I am confused with the following example.

```
class AClass extends Actor{
  def receive = {
    case B => println("Let's do B")
    case C => println("Let's do C")
  }
}

trait Request 
case object B extends Request 
case object C extends Request 

object Customer{ 

  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = { 

    val system = ActorSystem("Iwanttoeat") 
    val cook: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props[CookSomething])
    cook ! B
    cook ! C
  } 
}
```

I have three questions.

1. 'receive' method doesn't have an input parameter. What do I match something from? I guess it's from 'cook ! B'. ! means sends and forget.
   I am confused because no input parameter explicitly mentioned with the method, yet what do I compare B or C with?
2. I saw pattern matching examples. They have 'match' keyword.
   Is 'match' omitted before the curly bracket?

3.[not very important] why 'recieve' doesn't have a bracket? I wonder why it's not like recieve() = {...} I need your teaching!

Cheers

Seong

Comment: Receive is a partial function (`PartialFunction[Any, Unit]` to be exact), `{}` braces with case statements are just syntactic sugar to define those in scala. See [the partial function doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.PartialFunction) or feed a search engine with this.

Comment: Thank you, Alex for your comment. I have been thinking. I can see online that PartialFunction is often related to pattern matching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The receive method of an Akka actor is a partial function with signature `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]` as described in the [Akka Documentation](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/actor/Actor.html). In Scala, partial functions can be defined with a special syntax that omits the input variable and goes straight to the pattern matching. See [Effective Scala](http://twitter.github.io/effectivescala/#Functional%20programming-Partial%20functions) for more details.
2. See comment above about special syntax for partial functions.
3. In Scala, you can omit the parenthesis for methods that don't have any arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer. I now understand :)
I cite the following from the link you mentioned. 
instead of,
list map { item =>
  item match {
    case Some(x) => x
    case None => default
  }
}
collapse the match

list map {
  case Some(x) => x
  case None => default
}